# Oracle Text multi column index based query does not return any rows

Tags: oracle, text, oracle-text

I have a `MAH_KERESES_MV` table with 3 columns `OBJEKTUM_NEV`, `KERESES_SZOVEG_1`, `KERESES_SZOVEG_2`. I create the following multi column Oracle Text index:

```
exec ctx_ddl.create_preference( 'MAH_SEARCH', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
exec ctx_ddl.set_attribute('MAH_SEARCH', 'COLUMNS', 'OBJEKTUM_NEV, KERESES_SZOVEG_1, KERESES_SZOVEG_2');

create index MAX_KERES_CTX on MAH_KERESES_MV(OBJEKTUM_NEV)
  indextype is ctxsys.context
  parameters ('DATASTORE MAH_SEARCH');
```

But the query does not return any rows, although if I formulate the query with the `like` operator, then I get the results as expected:

```
SELECT  id, OBJEKTUM_NEV 
FROM MAH_KERESES_MV
WHERE CONTAINS(OBJEKTUM_NEV, 'C')>0;
```

Can some body please help? TIA,

Tamas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case any body might be interested later on, the solution was that the above CONTAINS clause filters for the C character as a stand alone entity (i.e. word). The correct where clause would have been:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(OBJEKTUM_NEV, 'C%')>0;
```